# Perform actions on uploaded file in Flask

Tags: flask

I want to make a simple Flask app that uploads a .txt file, and displays the number of letters inside it.

I tried this tutorial, without success:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/

Part of my code:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')



def uploaded_file(filename):
    f=send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                           filename)
    cout= Counter(letter for line in f 
                  for letter in line.lower() 
                      if letter in ascii_lowercase)
    return cout
```

my log:

TypeError
TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable

Comment: please show your error log.

Answer (score 1):

`send_from_directory` is a shortcut for serving files. I'm assuming what you are trying to do is read a file that you have previously uploaded.

```
import os

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) as f:
       cout = Counter(letter for line in f
                      for letter in line.lower()
                      if letter in str.ascii_lowercase)
    return cout
```

Comment: I tried it, and now I get: TypeError: 'Counter' object is not callable

Comment: do you have `from collections import Counter` at the top?

Comment: You can't return arbitrary things from an endpoint. Try using `jsonify(**cout)`. Don't forget to import it first.